# How do i get to know which rest client consuming xml or json data

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I am pretty new in rest full web services.I have one doubt how do i get to know which rest client consuming xml or json data. if multiple client are consuming my 
api at a same time.

Comment: With each request probably you can make a log table, in which you will insert 1 row per request along with the type i.e. xml or json. May be if you provide the sample url of your api then we can look better into it.

Comment: Are you trying to keep statistics or asking about how to prepare different formats of response?

Comment: Please give us more info. Why you need to know who is using the rest api?

Comment: actually this was asked in interview .can you guys give  an idea.

Answer (score 1):

As your REST Service uses the Content-Type HTTP header to specify the type of the returned content, the clients may specify their preferred content type using the Accept header.

The Accept header may event contain multiple content types with or without priority. (see [Mozilla content negotiation - the accept header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation#The_Accept_header))

If you want to identify the user of your API I would recommend the use of API Keys (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface_key)). This information may be combined with the detected accept header.

How to detect the accept header depends on the technology you are using to serve the REST service.